# Removing a popup menu contributed from another plugin

Tags: popup, contextmenu, rad

I'm having some problems trying to remove some plugin contributions to the additions insertion point from my context menu. In most of the cases I use activities and this works, as most of the contributions are done by actions. But in some other cases, the contributions are popup menus contributions and I cannot succeed disabling these entries. An example is the Source->Format menu contribution. The contribution is done by plugin org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui the following way:

```
  <menuContribution
       locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
    <menu
          id="sourceMenuId"
          label="%Source">
        <command
              commandId="org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.format"
              id="sourceFormat"
              style="push">
           <!-- Check to make sure that the handler is enabled before making visible -->
            <visibleWhen checkEnabled="true" />
        </command>
    </menu>
 </menuContribution>
```

I've been trying with patterns org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui/sourceFormat and with org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui/.*. They both work in Eclipe HELIOS but they do not work in RAD (Rational Application Developer 8.0.2).
  Is there any other way I can disable this popup menu contribution?. Can this issue be related with Eclipse version?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue (e.g.: Eclipse related right click menu entries appearing in my view) which I could fix using the following code.

The solution was the statement `getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);` which was missing from my application. This caused non view related selection entries creeping in and activating menu entries. Hope it helps someone struggling with the same issue.

```java
private void hookContextMenu() {
    MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager("#PopupMenu");  //$NON-NLS-1$
    ....

    Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(viewer.getControl());
    viewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);
    getSite().registerContextMenu(menuMgr, viewer);

    getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);
}
```